# How many $\Bbb{Q}$-algebras of dimension $4$ are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras

How can I construct $\Bbb{Q}$-algebras of dimension $4$.

Some examples that comes to mind  are $\Bbb{Q} \oplus \Bbb{Q} \oplus \Bbb{Q} \oplus \Bbb{Q}$ , rational quaternions $\Bbb{H}$ and $M_2(\Bbb{Q})$ ?

Is there a way to determine all of them upto isomorphism? How many are there?

$\Bbb{Q}$-algebras of dimension $< 4$ must be commutative, right?

So they will be $\Bbb{Q} \oplus \Bbb{Q} \oplus \Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q} \oplus \Bbb{Q} $ only.

Similarly how to go about finding , say $\Bbb{Q}$-algebras of dimension $n$.

Comment: Wouldn't the set $\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc} q_1 & q_2 \\ 0 & q_3\end{array}\right):q_1,q_2,q_3\in\Bbb Q\right\}$ be a dimension $3$ algebra which isn't commutative? You can do something similar for $2$ dimensions (use the top row). If you asked that they must be *division* algebras, I think it is true that they must be commutative if the dimension is less than $4$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes we will need division algebra condition to say less than $4$ dim are commutative. Thanks!

Comment: Any quadratic field is a commutative $\mathbb Q$-algebra of dimension $2$, and there are infinitely many of those. You get an infinite family of commutative $\mathbb Q$-algebras of dimension $4$ by taking the product of 2 quadratic fields. You get another infinite family of (non-commutative) $\mathbb Q$-algebras of dimension $4$ from the quaternion algebras.

Comment: There are also non-reduced algebras, such as $\mathbb Q[x]/x^4$.